# Exact word tapped on

Tags: windows-phone-8

When a user taps a `TextBlock` in Windows Phone 8, I would like to see the exact word he tapped on. Is that possible?

Comment: in your WinPhone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by using a separate `TextBlock` for each word (and putting them inside a wrap panel) and having them all use the same `Tap` event and using the `sender` of the event handler to determine the origin. It would then be easy to tell which one was tapped but it may be more overhead (in effort and memory) than you want. Particularly if you have a lot of "words".

The other alternative would be to use the `ManipulationCompleted` event to determine where the person released their finger. You could then calculate which word was at the location.
You'd probably want to combine this with use of the `ManipulatinoStarted` event so that you only handle actions/manipulations that resemble a true `Tap` event.

Both options are potentially a lot of work but I would argue that this is a non-standard request and so that is to be expected - unfortunately.

Comment: How can you calculate which word was at the location? Can know the width of characters?

Comment: To work out which word was touched you'd need to measure another instance of a `TextBlock` (with the same properties) and adjust the size of the text appropriately. Text wrapping might make some conditions where it may get harder to do this. You'd also have to be careful about how you handle the space between words and allow for the accuracy of a finger as a pixel specific pointing device.

Comment: I was actually thinking about that as well, yet wasn't sure if it was a good idea. I've managed to complete that and placed all the `TextBlock`s in a `WrapPanel`. Thanks!